Reference for the notion of quotient over a join-semilattice
In this question, a very natural way of defining the quotient of a join-semilattice over an ideal is described (in the community-wiki answer). This construction seems to differ from what it is usually called a quotient lattice (also because we are talking about join-semilattices instead of lattices).
I have two questions:

Is the construction in the community-wiki answer really different from quotient lattices?

Is there an explicit reference for the above construction? I've looked in both George Grätzer's Lattice Theory: Foundation (2011) and Garrett Birkhoff's Lattice Theory, but I've found nothing except from the usual quotient lattices.


Thanks

In the distributive lattice case, I found a specific reference to congruences defined from ideals as an exercise in the book Introduction to Lattices and Order, by Davey and Priestley.

@amrsa thank you for the answer. Is there an example of a quotient join-semilattice which is not defined by an ideal (but only by a congruence relation)?

@amrsa Yes, I was asking for was an explicit example.

Well trying to fill in the details, I just found that $\equiv_M$ is not an equivalence relation is, in general, not even an equivalence relation. It's not reflexive, unless the semilattice has a bottom element. Even then, I'm not sure about the other properties. It's certainly compatible with the operation.

@amrsa yes, I think $\equiv_M$ it is not propertly defined as it is. Maybe a better definition would be: $y_1 \equiv_M y_2$ if there exist $x_1, x_2 \in M$ such that $y_1 \preceq x_1 \vee y_2$ and $y_2\preceq x_2 \vee y_1$. Here $\preceq$ is the partial order on $L$.

That would still not be necessarily symmetric (again, it would depend on $M$).

@amrsa isn't the symmetry embedded in my definition? You would just need to swap $y_1, y_2$ and $x_1, x_2$.

@amrsa about the example, here is what I've thought. Consider $\mathbb{N}$ with its usual order (we consider it a join-semilattice). The quotients of $\mathbb{N}$ modulo its ideals (using the construction we are discussing) are only two (up to isomorphism): $0$ (the join-semilattice with only one element) or $\mathbb{N}$. But the map from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow {0,1}$ such that  $0 \mapsto 0$ and $n \mapsto 1$ for every $n > 0$ is a join-semilattice epimorphism. Therefore ${0,1}$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{N}$ which is not given by any ideal.

It's not symmetric: suppose the semillatice has the elements $a,b,1$ with $a,b < 1$ but $a$ and $b$ unrelated. Now suppose $M={a}$. It follows that $a \leq a \vee b$, thus $a\equiv_M b$, but $b \nleq a\vee a$ and so $b \not\equiv_M a$. The example with $\mathbb N$ seems ok. Meanwhile I'll delete some comments since we're getting the "extended discussions in comments" message.

@amrsa I don't get it, It seems to me that you are not considering the "and" in the definition of $\equiv_M$ I gave. The fact that $a \le a \vee b$ does not mean, according to my definition, that $a \equiv_M b$.

Ah, that's right! But once again, that's too restrictive and it won't give you all congruences. I don't think there is a point in trying to define quotients this way...

@amrsa right, I would like to give you the bounty but I don't know how unless you post an anwer...

The post is based on a misconception, and as such, I think the best thing is to wait until it expires and you get your 300 rep back, if nobody else postes an answer. I really wouldn't know what to post in an answer to this, specially after I myself have followed the mistake of the wrong answer this is based on. All the best!

I think this question no longer makes sense since you already changed in the comments. It might make sense to post a different question once the bounty expires and you can delete this post. Meanwhile, I noticed that the definition you proposed in the comments actually makes sense, provided $M$ is an ideal, and it coincides with the cleaner version: for $J$ an ideal of the semilattice, $$a\equiv_Jb \iff \exists u\in J(a\vee u=b\vee u).$$ Of course this still doesn't give all congruence relations (and thus, all quotient spaces).

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.
It seems that in this post you are trying to mimic the construction of quotient spaces that works for groups and vector spaces. If I understand correctly, your initial idea is to start with a subset $I$ of an ambient space $S$. Then you look for an appropriate equivalence relation $\sim_I$ on $S$ such that the quotient space shrinks the elements of $I$ to a single point. This works for groups with normal subgroups and for vector spaces with subspaces. Unfortunately, this idea fails in general.
For general algebraic structures, the right approach is to use congruences. You can look p. 35 in [1] for a general introduction. But let me first focus on the simple case of semigroups. By the way, note that a semilattice is a commutative and idempotent semigroup. A congruence on a semigroup $S$ is an equivalent relation $\sim$ such that, if $u \sim v$, then for all $x \in S$, one has $ux \sim vx$ and $xu \sim xv$. Of course, for a commutative semigroup, it suffices to verify one of the conditions.
Recall that a subset $I$ of a semigroup $S$ is an ideal if for all $x \in I$ and $s \in S$, one has $sx \in I$ and $xs \in I$. Now if you take a nonempty ideal, the relation $\sim_I$ defined on $S$ by
$$
u \sim_I v \iff (u = v) \text{ or } (u, v \in I)
$$
is a congruence and hence there is a well defined quotient semigroup $S/{\sim_I}$, usually simply denoted by $S/I$, in which the elements of $I$ shrink to a single point. However,
there are in general many other congruences on a semigroup, and even on
a join semilattice. Think for instance of the congruence $a \sim b$ in the semilattice $\{1, a, b, 0\}$ with $ab = 0$.
Another equivalent approach (for algebraic structures again), is simply to define quotient spaces as the image of a surjective morphism. For instance, if $\varphi: S \to T$ is a surjective semigroup morphism, then the equivalence $\sim_\varphi$ defined on $S$ by
$$
u \sim_\varphi t \iff \varphi(u) = \varphi(t)
$$
is a congruence, called the nuclear congruence of $\varphi$. Conversely, if $\sim$ is a congruence on $S$, then the natural map $S \to S/{\sim}$ is a surjective morphism.
For more complex structures, like ordered or topological structures, things become more complicated and a category-theoretic approach becomes helpful. But for semilattices and lattices, congruences / surjective morphisms suffice.
[1] Burris and Sankappanavar, A course in universal algebra, 2012 Update.
